# optimizing a multi-week mysql query with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, optimization

I have a script that queries a database of 50,000 records and attempts to create a table outlining a weekly report of total new entries into the database each week.

I have a constraint: the report must begin at `$START_DATE`, which is the first day there exist records for any users in the database under each part of the website. This means I can't use a function which looks up pre-defined dates, I must count users in sections bounded by the first second the first user entered the database until exactly one week later, up until an `$END_DATE` which is usually simply `time()`.

It takes approximately 5 seconds to query the database for a `count(*)` or `select *`:

```
mysql> select count(*), user_type from users_table where user_permissions = "normal" group by user_type;
+----------+-----------------+
| count(*) | user_type       |
+----------+-----------------+
|     2210 | myspace_user    | 
|    48659 | facebook_user   | 
+----------+-----------------+
2 rows in set (4.73 sec)
```

I have some PHP code that goes through and queries the database a bunch of times per `user_type` to get a detailed table of reports for each week. The problem is, there are 12 weeks and two user types so the entire process takes up to two minutes. Some parts of the site have more than two user types, and these queries take even longer. Here's the code:

```
$start = strtotime($START_DATE);
$end = strtotime($END_DATE);
for ($i = 0; $start+$i < time() && $start+$i < $end; $i+= (7*24*60*60)) {
    $weekly_total = 0;
    foreach($USERTYPES as $usertype) {
        $q = "select count(*) from users_table where user_type = '" . $usertype . "' and user_permissions = 'normal'";
        $q .= " and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestmp) >= " . strval($start+$i) . " and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestmp) <= " . strval($start+$i+(7*24*60*60));
        $r = mysql_query($q);
        $v = mysql_fetch_array($r);
        $table['weekly'][gmdate("Y-m-d", $start+$i)][$usertype] += $v[0];
        $weekly_total += $v[0];
    }
    $table['weekly'][gmdate("Y-m-d", $start+$i)]['weekly_total'] = $weekly_total;
}
```

Finally I have an array with 12 entries, with a basic structure that ends up like this pseudocode:

```
// ...previous entries
$table['weekly']['2013-07-01'] = array(
    'myspace_user' => 123,
    'facebook_user' => 1234,
    'weekly_total' => 1357
);
$table['weekly']['2013-07-08'] = array(
// ...and so on
```

The process which generates these queries and saves them to the table takes too long. Is there any way I can make this more efficient with MySQL or PHP functions, so I don't have to generate a separate query for each week?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incredibly inefficient, forcing multiple date->timestamp conversions on both sides of the fence (PHP and MySQL). Why not have a much more simple

```
$start = '2013-07-16';

for ($week = 0; $week < 52; $week++) {
    SELECT ...
    ...
    WHERE timestmp BETWEEN ($start + INTERVAL $week WEEK)
        AND ($start + INTERVAL $week WEEK + INTERVAL 7 DAY)
}
```

You'll stick with native MySQL datetime values, without all the repeated native->int->native->whatever conversions.

Comment: Each of those SELECT queries takes 4.75 seconds, exactly the same as mine. The entire process of calculating 12 weeks for 2 types still takes 2 minutes. The date->timestamp conversions from int to string take a negligible amount of time and are for display purposes (also because I don't have control over how some of that data arrives at my doorstep).

Comment: You could also reduce it to a single query by just having the lowest/highest possible date ranges, and pulling out a derived field, e.g `WEEK(timestmp)` so you can identify which period the record should be in.

Comment: @joey: if the SELECT itself takes 4.75 seconds, there's probably something wrong with the way the table is structured... How many records are there? Is `user_type` indexed? Is `user_permissions` a string, perhaps? Making the wrong choice here will impact your query a lot.

Comment: There are many records. Neither of these fields are indexed, which is for a separate but sound reason. `user_permissions` is indeed a string.